# AJAX not receiving response from backend, works on localhost but not on deployed server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

My POST request's response is not being received and gets a 504 error, though it works perfectly on my local machine.

Everything is working in the backend as confirmed by the debugger, and another page on my site with the same AJAX code works perfectly well. I'm not sure what the issue could be. I've attached code snippets below:

**In my webpage (the URL is basesite.com/tables/listallusers)**

```
$.ajax(
  url: "/assignuser"
  type: "POST"
  data: JSON.stringify(request_object)// already been defined before
  datatype: "json"
  contentType: "application/json"
  
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log(data) // This is the data to be returned by the AJAX call
  }
  error: function(request)
  {
    console.log("An error has occurred")
  }
```

**In the backend (done in flask)**

```
@app.route("/assignuser", methods=['POST'])
def assign_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        assignuser(request.json)
        return "User has been assigned"
    return "An error has occured"
```

This code works on my localhost but not when deployed on the cloud, giving a 504 error.

Comment: When debugging AJAX issues, open devtools and go to the network tab. Make the request and check the response there. You will be able to see the status code and response text. In a development environment the latter should hopefully contain an error message and stack trace you can debug.

Comment: 504 - gateway timeout - *A Gateway might refer to different things in networking and a 504 error is usually not something you can fix, but requires a fix by the web server or the proxies you are trying to get access through.*